# How to update list in list in ImmutableJS?

Tags: immutable.js

I have problems updating a list inside a list in ImmutableJS. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var rows = Immutable.List();
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  rows = rows.push({type:"floor"});
}

var cols = Immutable.List();
for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
  cols = cols.push(rows);
}

var wall = {type:"wall"};

cols = cols.update(cols.get(3).get(4), function(wall) { return wall});

// I expect to get 'wall' written in the console, but the output is 'floor'.
console.log(cols.get(3).get(4).type);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.7.6/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: "*Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?*" - can you tell us what's the problem?

Comment: Looks like you are doing absolutely nothing here (at least nothing that you expect) : `cols = cols.update(cols.get(3).get(4), function(wall) { return wall});` (The updater just returns the argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate updating into two steps (see example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrt0c4em/)):

```
var rows = Immutable.List();
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  rows = rows.push({type:"floor"});
}

var cols = Immutable.List();
for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
  cols = cols.push(rows);
}

var wall = {type:"wall"};
var nestedList = cols.get(3);
var newNestedList;
var newCols;
newNestedList = nestedList.update(4, function(item) {return wall});
newCols = cols.update(3, function(list) { return newNestedList});
console.log(newCols.get(3).get(4).type);
```